# How to open .msu extension file?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-update

I have downloaded a file WINDOWS POWERSHELL that has an .msu extension how do i install this package in my winxp professional sp3 OS.

Comment: For Windows XP the answer to this question seems to be in an answer to this question at superuser.SE: http://superuser.com/questions/628392/how-do-you-open-a-msu-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is this link on microsoft support site that explains how to install the .msu file:

- [Description of the Windows Update Standalone Installer in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/934307)

Comment: Did an older version of that article include information about XP? It's not there now. (I think XP is almost entirely scrubbed from Microsoft's site.)